# How to validate back, Captcha google magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have already connected it, but you can safely bypass it, how can this check be improved?

```
<?php

class RonisBT_Feedback_Model_Captcha
{
    public function captcha()
    {
        if (Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $captcha = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('g-recaptcha-response', 1);
            if ($captcha == '' || $captcha == 1) {
                $error= Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Please check the reCAPTCHA field to continue.');
                return $error;
            } else {
                $secret = Mage::getStoreConfig(RonisBT_Feedback_Model_Source_Paths::SETTING_CAPTCHA_KEY);
                $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . $secret . '&response=' . $captcha . '&remoteip=' . Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr();
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the form

```
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?></div>
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo Mage::helper('feedback')->__('Feedback') ?></h1>
</div>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('feedback/index/post'); ?>" id="feedback" method="post" class="scaffold-form">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <h2 class="legend"><?php echo Mage::helper('feedback')->__('Feedback Information') ?></h2>
        <p class="required"><?php echo Mage::helper('feedback')->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li class="fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="name" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?>
                    </label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input name="name" id="name"
                               title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name')) ?>"
                               value="<?php echo $this->getFeedbackName(); ?>" class="input-text required-entry"
                               type="text"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?>
                    </label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input name="email" id="email"
                               title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email')) ?>"
                               value="<?php echo $this->getFeedbackEmail(); ?>"
                               class="input-text required-entry validate-email" type="email" autocapitalize="off"
                               autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="telephone"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input name="phone" id="phone"
                           title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone')) ?>"
                           value="<?php echo $this->getFeedbackPhone(); ?>" class="input-text" type="tel"/>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="fields">
                <div class="select_subject">
                    <span class="label-subject">Subject:</span>
                    <select class="ronis_select required-entry select" id="select_feedback" name="subject"
                            onchange="admSelectCheck(this);"">
                    <?php foreach (Mage::getModel('feedback/source_subject')->toArray() as $subject): ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo($subject); ?>" <?php echo ($subject == 'Other') ? 'id="admOther"' : '' ?> ><?php echo($subject); ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div id="ifYes" style="display: none;">
                    <br><input type="text" id="input_other" name="other_subject" placeholder="Your subject">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="wide">
                <textarea class="required-entry" name="message" placeholder="Message..."
                          rows="3"><?php echo $this->getFeedbackMessage(); ?></textarea>
            </li>
            <?php if ($this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()): ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo Mage::helper('feedback')->getSiteKey(); ?>"></div>
                    <span id="captcha-required"
                          style='display:none; color:#ff0000'><?php echo $this->__('Please Fill Recaptcha To Continue'); ?></span>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <button type="submit"
                title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit')) ?>"
                class="button"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Send') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var contactForm = new VarienForm('feedback', true);
    //]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this in your template:

```
<? if (isset($_POST['submit'])):
        $checkReCaptcha =  true;
        $g_response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        if (isset($g_response) && !empty($g_response)):
            if (!(Mage::helper('googlecaptcha')->validateCaptcha($g_response))):
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('ReCAPTCHA not valid');
                $checkReCaptcha = false;
            endif;
        else:
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Please click on the reCAPTCHA box');
            $checkReCaptcha = false;
        endif;
    endif;
    ?>
```

Helper/Data.php

```
<?php

class RonisBT_Feedback_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

/**
 * path to field text on admin
 */
const SECRETKEY = 'enter the path of secret key';

/**
 * Validate catpcha based on response from the google
 * @param $response
 * @return bool
 */
public function validateCaptcha($response)
{
    $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . $this->getSecretkey() . '&response=' . $response);
    $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
    if ($responseData->success):
        return true;
    else:
        return false;
    endif;
}

/**
 * Get secret key configuration
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getSecretkey()
{
    return Mage::getStoreConfig(self::SECRETKEY);
}

}
```

Comment: validateCaptcha I do not have this method, that it should have ?

Comment: updated my answer, you can use a helper instead of a model , its your choice, or you can modify as you want the call of the function

Comment: always goes to $eror = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('ReCAPTCHA not valid'); even if when the captcha introduced